# I can't figure out how to calculate the value of each customer for their first year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate how much each customer spends in their first year with us but I'm struggling with how to format the query. So far I have:

```
select customerId, sum(total)
from cms2_orders
where customerId = 254063
and
(dtc between
    (select min(dtc)
    from cms2_orders
    group by customerId
    )
AND
    (select (date_add(min(dtc), interval 1 year))
    from cms2_orders))
group by customerId
```

I know the problem is with the 'group by' on line 8 but if that is not present, it is interpreted as the first order ever placed by anyone. Is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cleaner way of doing this is to use a subquery to calculate the start date for each customer, and then join this to your main query to remove records from the total which did not occur in the first year.

```
SELECT t1.customerid,
       SUM(t1.total)
FROM cms2_orders t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT customerid,
           MIN(dtc) AS dtc_start
    FROM cms2_orders
    GROUP BY customerid
) t2
    ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid
WHERE t1.dtc BETWEEN t2.dtc_start AND DATEADD(t2.dtc_start, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY t1.customerid
```

Comment: This query worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

here's the different way, hope it works

```
select customerid, sum(total)
from cms2_orders
where customerId = 254063
and year(dtc) = year(min(dtc))
```